# Encrypt body response on nginx

Tags: nginx, aes

I'm trying to read the response file and encrypted with AES-cdc through nginx configuration.

Something like that GET `/encrypt/file.txt`
Response `content_of_file_encrypted`

Is there a way to do it by nginx modules? or do I need to encrypt it with another tool before?

Thanks